# Can I change an O365 2013 office install to a retail license?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, license, office365

If I install a retail license of MS Office 2013 on a computer, anyone who logs into that computer can use the software correct?- just want to make sure MS hasn't made any changes to the basic retail licensing scheme.

Right now we have Office 365 installed on a PC, but obviously only people with O365 accounts can use it.

Now I don't want O365 on that PC, I want a retail 2013 license.

What happens if I install a retail 2013 license on the PC? If I have a retail license can I just change the license type as 2013 is already installed its just it was using O365 licensing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  The retail license is per machine, not user.

If you install it new, when you first start up it should ask you to sign in with your Microsoft Account.  If you look below that there should be a small link to enter a product key that you can use instead.

[image]

I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you disable the ProPlus license on a signed in user - you will get a warning the product is not activated, and you may have an opportunity to enter key to activate here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid Office 2013 retail key you can do the following:

Open a Command Prompt window, and then take one of the following actions:

> • If you installed the 64-bit version of Office 2013, move to the
>   following folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15
>
> • If you installed the 32-bit version of Office 2013, move to the
>   following folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15

Type the following command to display the license status. Note the last five characters of any and all license keys that display in the output:

> cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus

Now run the following command as many times as needed to remove all of the license keys you noted from the previous step.

> cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:

Once the remove commands are successful, close the command prompt and restart the PC.

Launch one of the MS Office 2013 applications (I like to use Word). The application should prompt you to reactivate the by providing your sign-on ID. Enter in the new user's credentials and the software will now be licensed under their ID.

Comment: "Enter in the new user's credentials and the software will now be licensed under their ID"- you mean enter the retail license? I want to use a retail license so any user that logs into the computer can use office- I don't want the license attached to specific user account, but be system wide.

Comment: That requires you Sysprep the computer with the office installed and activated